# Ada95: How to use Float in Exponent?

Tags: floating-point, ada, exponent

What I've tried:

```
 function Get_T(I : in Integer)
                return Float is
    T:Float;
    M:Float:=Float(I);
  begin
    T:=40.0*0.5**((60.0-M)/20.0);  -- FLOAT NOT ACCEPTED IN EXPONENT
    return T;
  end Get_T;
```

Do I need a special package? I've been looking at Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize power operator defined in `Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions` package:

```
With Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;

function Get_T(I : in Integer) return Float is
    use Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
    T: Float;
    M: Float := Float(I);
begin
    T := 40.0 * 0.5 ** ((60.0 - M) / 20.0);
    return T;
end Get_T;
```

Comment: You could use `Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions`, which is `Generic_Elementary_Functions` already instantiated for `Float`.